# put variable into sed with bash

Tags: bash, variables, sed, double-quotes, quote

I try to use a variable in a **sed** of **bash**

I have this code :

```
read -p "Repertoire destination: " REP
echo $REP

sed -i 's/\$app\[\"bundle.root\"\] = \"\/var\/www\/\"\;/\$app\[\"bundle.root\"] = \"'$REP'\"\;/'  /home/martialp/Documents/default.php

echo "Modification terminé"
```

I use simple quote like '$REP' but i have this error :

```
sed: -e expression n°1, caractère 80: option inconnue pour `s'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trouble is probably that `$REP` contains slashes, but you're using `/` to delimit the regular expression.  The easiest fix is to use some other character to delimit the regular expression, perhaps `%`:

```
sed -i 's%\$app\[\"bundle.root\"\] = \"\/var\/www\/\"\;%\$app\[\"bundle.root\"] = \"'$REP'\"\;%'  /home/martialp/Documents/default.php
```

You can use any character that doesn't otherwise appear in the command; <kbd>Control-A</kbd>, for example, works well and is unlikely to appear in `$REP`.